# Sort by stock and date created on product catalog on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to sort first all products with stock and by a date (as a publication or creation date on product attributes) on DESC order

I found this method to sort by product stock first (using it on theme `functions.php`). It is working very well but need to do a second (less privileged) sort on a publication date (or equivalent) on product attributes

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_sort_by_date_created', 10 );

function custom_sort_by_stock ( $args ) {
   $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
   $args['order'] = 'ASC';
   $args['meta_key'] = '_stock_status';
   return $args;
}
```

Tried adding a second filter function given it 20 as privilege but it doesn't do anything on the order of catalog

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_sort_by_stock', 20 );

function custom_sort_by_date_created ( $args ) {
   $args['orderby'] = 'date'; // date_created
   $args['order'] = 'DESC';
   return $args;
}
```